# What are possible problems switching from MSXML4 to MSXML6?

Tags: windows, xml, msxml

Due to problems associated with installing MSXML4 ([like this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2266961.php)) we want to switch to MSXML6. Are there any known issues associated with this or is such transition smooth and painless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment isn't so much about the 4 to 6 transition as it is about the MSXML6 installer itself.  Apparently some people do experience problems getting it installed properly.  When not properly installed, it breaks the Add-In Manager in Visual Studio.

Quote from [this page](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007009.aspx):

"There is a reported problem that happens when MSXML 6.0 is not installed correctly. In this case the Add-In Manager doesn't show any XML-based add-in (using an .AddIn file for registration). It shows only registry-based add-ins. So, if the Add-In Manager is empty when it should show several installed add-ins (not only yours), try reinstalling MSXML 6.0."